# Find the number of distinct arrangements.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> There are $5$ white, $4$ yellow, $3$ green, $2$ blue and $1$ red ball.The balls are all identical except for colour. These are arranged in a line in $5$ places. Find the number of distinct arrangements.

My attempt:

The $7$ cases are:

1. $1, 1, 1, 1, 1 \to \binom{5}{5}5! $
2. $2, 1, 1, 1 \to \frac{\binom{4}{3}\binom{4}{1}5!}{2!}$
3. $2, 2, 1 \to \frac{\binom{4}{2}\binom{3}{1}5!}{2!2!}$
4. $2, 3 \to \frac{\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{1}5!}{2!3!}$
5. $3, 1, 1 \to \frac{\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{2}5!}{3!}$
6. $4, 1 \to \frac{\binom{2}{1}\binom{4}{1}5!}{4!}$
7. $5 \to 1$

The sum of these turns out be $2171$ but the answer is $2111$. What is my mistake?

Comment: You need to format your question a little better...  It looks like one big run-on...

Comment: What does "4c3" mean, does it mean "4 choose 3"?  Also, it would be helpful if you gave us your justification for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are calculating these cases correctly, although I may be misreading some of your answers.  I think the count for each case is

$1)\quad 5!=120$

$2)\quad 4\times4\times5\times4\times3=960$

$3)\quad 6\times3\times30=540$

$4)\quad 3\times3\times10=90$

$5)\quad 3\times6\times5\times4=360$

$6)\quad 2\times4\times5=40$

$7)\quad 1$

So $$120 + 960 + 540 + 90 + 360 + 40 + 1 = 2111$$